# React Native - stopping the setTimeOut then continue after enable GPS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-native

So I have a SplashScreen, I don't want to navigate it yet to AuthScreen.js until the gps is enabled. How do I do that?

In my case right now, it doesn't work, the Modal of GPS will show but the the setTimeOut is running or the SplashScreen is navigating after 1000 to AuthScreen.

What I want is to stop the setTimeOut which is 1000, it will just continue to count after the gps enabled then it will navigate to AuthScreen.js.

I already tried to stop the SplashScreen, but I used the PermissionAndroid not the GPS or LocationServicesDialog. So I'm trying now is the GPS Location, and after it works ill try to run the Permission Android and the GPS Location at the same time but don't worry about this for now. Let's just focus on GPS right now. Thank you!

```
async function requestGPStoEnable() {
try {
let check = await LocationServicesDialogBox.checkLocationServicesIsEnabled({
  message: "<h2>Use Location?</h2> \
  This app wants to change your device settings:<br/><br/>\
  Use GPS for location<br/><br/>",
  ok: "Yes",
  cancel: "No",
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  showDialog: true,
  openLocationServices: true,
  preventOutSideTouch: true,
  preventBackClick: true,
  providerListener: true
}).then(function(success) {
  console.log(success);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error.message);
});
} catch (err) {
 console.warn(err);
}
}

class SplashScreen extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);

 this.state = {
   timePassed: false
 };
}

componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout( () => {
    this.setTimePassed();
  }, 1000)

  requestGPStoEnable();
};

  gpsLocation() {
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  LocationServicesDialogBox.checkLocationServicesIsEnabled({
    message: "<h2>Use Location?</h2> \
    This app wants to change your device settings:<br/><br/>\
    Use GPS for location<br/><br/>",
    ok: "Yes",
    cancel: "No",
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    showDialog: true,
    openLocationServices: true,
    preventOutSideTouch: true,
    preventBackClick: true,
    providerListener: true
  }).then(function(success) {
    console.log(success);
    // this.setTimePassed();
    setTimeout( () => {
      this.setTimePassed();
    }, 1000)
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message);
  });
}
}

setTimePassed() {
  this.setState({timePassed: true})
};

render() {
 if(!this.state.timePassed) {
   return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <Text>Hello</Text>
     </View>
   );
 } else {
  return <AuthScreen/>
 }
 };
};
```

Comment: dont set the timer till the success for gps is called?

Comment: I tried to put `this.setTimePassed();` inside the `then(function(success){}` but still not working

Comment: Fyi, i have also a function of `requestGPStoEnable()` inside the Component Class

Comment: well thats because its not a part of the component

Comment: why not just `await requestGPStoEnable()` then `setTimeout()`?

Comment: I mean i put the `this.setTimePassed();` inside the `.then(function(success){}` but for the `requestGPStoEnable()` that is inside the Component Class. I have 2 `requestGPStoEnable()` 1 outside the Component, and 1 inside the Component for troubleshoot.

Comment: well then post the actual code so we can help

Comment: Already added the requestGPStoEnable inside the Component

Comment: you arent calling that function in this code, is that how the other code is? You need to use an arrow so that you have `this` bound. `.then( success =>`

Comment: Yea, for troubleshoot. Sometimes I comment out the requestGPStoEnable outside the Component to use the requestGPStoEnable inside the component.

Comment: You should just have one. and make sure you bind the success to your class

Comment: Can you post your answer? So we're not overload in the comment section. Thanks

Comment: I already added the arrow but still now work.